# Can a ViewList have Groups and Columns?

Tags: vb.net, listview, grouping, multiple-columns

I have a ViewList with groups (ListView.View = Details). Now I'm trying to add Columns to it and I can. But when I run the code it gives an error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Waarde van 1 is niet geldig voor index.
```

Is it possible to have groups and columns in a ListView?

Piece of code:

```
                        Dim item = New ListViewItem()
                        item.Text = gelijke_titel.Artiest & " - " & gelijke_titel.Titel & " " & BepaalBestandsgrootte(gelijke_titel.Bestandsnaam)
         error -->      item.SubItems(1).Text = song.Map
                        item.Group = groep
                        titels_gevonden.Add(item)
```

Comment: [item.SubItems.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitemcollection.add). You need to add a SubItem before you can set any of it's properties. Or use one of the `Add()` method overloads. See the Docs.

Comment: If I do 'item.SubItems.Add()' it gives '
Error-BC30516 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' accepts this number of arguments. NameIt C:\Users\Hansje\Documents\Projecten\NameIt 2.0\NameIt\frm_BestandsnaamVergelijken.vb 154 Active
'

Comment: When I add a digit in between the brackets its working! Thank you Jimi!

Comment: I've linked the Docs about this method for a reason :)

Comment: Where can I find these 'Docs' Jimi? (There is Google and so on, but now I've got you?!?!) (And why can't I give you an 'Up' for helping me?

Comment: *"Where can I find these 'Docs'"*. Well, for one thing, @Jimi provided a link to the relevant page in the documentation and then also specifically told you that they had done so, so there's really no "finding" to be done. Secondly, I just searched the web for "vb.net documentation" and, no surprise, I "found" links to the documentation pages in less than a second. Finally, VS has a Help menu, just as Windows applications have had for decades. I find it quite staggering how bad so many people - certainly not just you - are at finding information. Many seem to expect it to find them.

Comment: I get 'your grip' jmcilhinney! You are right! When everything is so easy to find why have this website at all? Why are you still here? And why did you search for "vb.net documentation" via Google (or such)?